# Triggering an update on a second table after insert

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables, A and P.

```
     A
________________
id   |  num_cars
----------
1    |  2
2    |  0
3       0

             P
__________________________
id_driver    |      id_car
--------------------------
1            |    Porsche
1            |    BMW
```

A.id and P.id_driver referes to the same person. I created the below trigger. The idea is, every time I add a new row in P for an existing driver its correspondent row in A must be updated with the number of total cars owned by the person with that id.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_a() RETURNS trigger AS $$ 
BEGIN
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    UPDATE A a
      SET num_cars = (SELECT COUNT(NEW.id_driver)
      FROM P p
      WHERE (a.id = p.id_driver AND a.id=NEW.id_driver));
ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
    UPDATE A a 
      SET num_cars = num_cars - 1
      WHERE a.id = OLD.id_driver AND a.num_cars<>0;
END IF;        
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER add_car
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON PARTICIPATION
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_a();
```

The trigger works fine when I add a row in B for a driver. However, if I then add a row for a different driver in B the rest of the rows in A are set back to 0. I would like the procedure to run only when A.id = P.id_driver. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe because you're calling `update_car` in your trigger and not `update_a` or is that a typo?

Comment: I've corrected the typo, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update query makes a cross product between `A` and `P`, and therefore updates the entire table, counting 0 cars most of the time.

You would need to restrict the update to the proper driver only, and also to compute the number of cars only for this driver:

```sql
UPDATE A a
SET num_cars = (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM P p
      WHERE p.id_driver = NEW.id_driver)
WHERE a.id = NEW.id_driver;
```

Comment: I upvoted it, but my votes don't show because my account doesn't have enough points.